# To draw a checkbox in dart, is using paint class or something is the better way or is there some other ideas without using `checkBox` class

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to draw a `checkbox` in dart using `paint class` or something? I don't like the difficulty of customizability of the current official `checkBox` with always have to wrap it with `materials` library. My idea is to draw a square with `customPaint` class and `stack positioning` a `tick` icon in the mid and placing a `gesture detector` to detect clicks, to check and uncheck the `tick`? Is there any other elegant way of doing it? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes it is possible as you describe, you can use `customPaint`,`ClipPath` or `Stack` based on your design. But are the things you like to have on official checkbox?

Comment: see [ToggleableStateMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleableStateMixin-mixin.html) and [ToggleablePainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleablePainter-class.html) - the mixin is used by `_MaterialSwitchState`, `_CheckboxState` and `_RadioState`

Comment: Why need to create something new when there is already a better solution out there?.  "I don't like the difficulty of customizability of the current official checkBox with always have to wrap it with materials library." As you mention here, you can just make it a custom widget where you change the widget based on your liking.

Comment: You could also just create a `StatefulWidget` with an `isSelected` state that changes on click, and show different Icons depending on the state. In my opinion, custom paint would be overkill.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh thanks for the clippath suggestion. :)

Comment: @pskink thanks for the mixin suggestions and already reading the links you provided. thank you :)

Comment: @StefanGaller thanks for the suggestion, hope many sateful widgets will not cause the apps to slow down.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, `StatefulWidgets` are more efficient than `customPaint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Please refer below code

```
class _CustomCheckBoxState extends State<CustomCheckBox> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Custom Check Box",
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isChecked = !isChecked;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 20.0,
                    height: 20.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 0.7,
                      horizontal: 0.7,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(64, 212, 232, 0.18),
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Color(0xff40D4E8),
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                    ),
                    child: (isChecked == true)
                        ? Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.check,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              size: 16.0,
                            ),
                          )
                        : Container(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```